# MS Graph Angular search for user by name

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

In my Angular App, there should be an option to search for users within the organization.
The application itself is protected by MSAL library, and the access token is added to all Request Headers by MsalInterceptor.

Now I want to search for Users, who starts with 'Joh' by HttpClientModule:

```
this.http.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Joh')`, { headers: { ConsistencyLevel: 'eventual' } }).subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-15

Unfortunately, I'm facing the following error:

> "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a
> property named 'displayName' on type
> 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Web.Models._1._0.Profile'."

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This query works on Graph Explorer as is. Seems like an issue with the http module or the type. I will try and get back.

Comment: I have just tried your exact code on a sample ng component. The query runs as expected. May be share more context . May be the whole component code.